# Django and Angular POST credentials were not provided

Tags: django

error when i try to login to my proyect, im using postman for test the login and send me error
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

my url.py

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^api-login-user$', views.LoginUserView.as_view()),
   url(r'^', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='angular/index.html')),
     url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^auth/', ObtainAuthToken.as_view()),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
   ]
```

my view.py

```
class LoginUserView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
            token = {
                'token': jwt.encode(payload, SECRET_KEY),
                'status': 'success'
                }            
            return Response(token)
        else:
            return Response(
              {'error': 'Invalid credentials',
              'status': 'failed'},
            )
```

my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = { 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
           'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny', 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser' 
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', 
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ],

     'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
}
```

Comment: and how do you send the request params in postman ?

Comment: now send me other error "zone.js:2969 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-login-user 401 (Unauthorized)" when i try login, i send data with json btw

Comment: You are using django_restframework_apiview but your code lacks some important parts, look at this as reference  https://github.com/007gzs/django_restframework_apiview, also, you could try sending credential info in form-data instead of json just to be sure